What does "four corners" mean here?
What does "four corners" mean here? A studio, or a room in an apartment?

In our area, an apartment is nearly $2000 for four corners.

Which sense in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corner does "corner" take?

More context is required, obviously. That said, Four Corners is a geographical location in the US. You can google it.

If there are only four corners, it is a single-room "studio" apartment.  It is not a standard collocation but a witticism.

What @TimR said. The joke being that $2000 might only cover the cost of a broom cupboard rented out as living accommodation. If you want enough space to swing a cat, it'll cost extra.

Four corners and nothing between them.

We use sense 1a of M+W:

the point where converging lines, edges, or sides meet

Here it means the point where two walls meet.  There are four of them.
The writer has used four corners to refer to such an apartment, probably a small one, to mean the rental is expensive.

It's not a standard expression, or one that I've ever encountered.  I suppose it might mean a simple one-room apartment - just a space with four walls (but, which technically could be said to have EIGHT corners!)  We're looking at meanings 1 or 2.  I think we can confidently discount meanings 3, 4 and 5.
